# Check whether Spark Dataframes are equal or not?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am comparing two large dataframes about 100gb in pyspark, but before going into row level and column level validation, need to compare if there are indeeed some differences between the two dataframes.

I need a way I can generate a checksum or similar method for both dataframes which I can compare and say they are equal or not.

This is one way which I found which works with small dataset for both dataframes and compare if they are same, but unfortunately it will give me out of bounds memory for larger dataset since there is so much data to process.

```
df1=spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").csv(file1)
print(hashlib.sha256(df1.toPandas().to_json().encode()).hexdigest())
```

Is there anyway, we can compare initially before going brute force for comparison?

Comment: In Spark, it seems impossible, as your data should all reside inside one node to calculate a deterministic checksum. It's unlikely with big data. What your small code does, is collecting the whole table into one node. That's why it works. One node will be too small for your big data table.

Comment: What if we choose multiple nodes, partition wouldn't work I guess in this case, since we want a checksum of whole dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

intersect method of dataframe may be a solution.

```
   intersectcount = df1.intersect(df2).count()
   if (intersectcount == df1.count()) && (intersectcount==df2.count()):
       #Equal dataframes
```

Comment: this will just count the number of rows which are common to both dataframes, for a large dataframe all counts will result in a lot of time for comparison. What we need is a quick way to know if the dataframes are indeed different or not and then go for real comparison.